# Sheaf homology defined in terms of Tor

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

By the general philosophy of [cohomology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cohomology), cohomology is essentially derived $\operatorname{Hom}$ (i.e. $\operatorname{Ext}$), and homology should be derived tensor product (i.e. $\operatorname{Tor}$).

For example, given a topological space $X$, a commutative ring $K$, and $K_X$ the corresponding constant sheaf on $X$, then the sheaf cohomology of $X$ with coefficients in a sheaf of $K$-modules $\mathcal{V}$ can be defined as
$$H^\bullet(X; \mathcal{V}) := \operatorname{Ext}^\bullet_{K_X}(K_X, \mathcal{V}).$$
This agrees with the more common definition of sheaf cohomology as right-derived global sections.

In contrast to sheaf cohomology, I haven't really seen sheaf homology discussed very much. Would it be correct to say that
$$H_\bullet(X; \mathcal{V}) := \operatorname{Tor}_\bullet^{K_X}(K_X, \mathcal{V}),$$
or does the established definition of sheaf homology deviate from the usual pattern? Also, are there any common applications of sheaf homology?

Comment: There are two kinds of Hom (which are related, but nonetheless different). You need to pay more attention to the domain and codomain of the functors you work with. The Hom that gives you global sections takes sheaves to modules, so its left adjoint takes modules to sheaves. Taking the left derived functor of that gives you a funny homology that takes module coefficients to produce sheaf-valued homology objects.

Comment: @ZhenLin is that what people usually think of as sheaf homology?

Comment: No. There is nothing that is usually called sheaf homology, as far as I know.